# Aber sie täuschen sich nur/nur sich

Tags: colloquial

Was ist richtig?

> Meine Eltern glauben, sie könnten mich davon abhalten, meine Lebensziele zu erreichen! Aber **sie täuschen nur sich**.

> Meine Eltern glauben, sie könnten mich davon abhalten, meine Lebensziele zu erreichen! Aber **sie täuschen sich nur**.

Comment: Wiederum: beides ist richtig. Aber die Bedeutung ist unterschiedlich.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Auch ich halte beide Sätze für problematisch, weil in beiden Fällen das *'nur'* und auch das '*täuschen*' nicht passt. Ich paraphrasiere sie einmal so, wie ich sie verstehe.

Satz 1:

- Meine Eltern glauben, sie könnten mich davon abhalten, meine
  Lebensziele zu erreichen! Aber das glauben auch nur sie! [= *die Eltern*]

oder:

- ... Aber da täuschen sie sich, ich werde es ihnen (schon noch) beweisen!

oder

- ... aber **mich** können sie nicht überzeugen.

oder:

- Meine Eltern versuchen, mir einzureden, dass ich meine Lebensziele nicht erreichen kann. Aber ich werde nicht darauf hereinfallen.
- ... aber ich schenke ihren Reden keinen Glauben.

Satz 2

- Meine Eltern sind überzeugt, sie könnten mich davon abhalten, meine Lebensziele zu erreichen! Aber damit machen sie sich nur selbst etwas vor.
- ...(besser:) aber da irren sie sich.
- ...(umgangssprachlich:) aber damit lügen sie sich nur selbst etwas in die Tasche.

Das Verb *täuschen* passt hier meistens nicht, weil es um Überzeugungen und um Glauben geht und nicht um die Wahrheit. Jemanden '*täuschen*' heißt, ihm die Unwahrheit oder irgendwelche Halbwahrheiten sagen. Man kann jedoch über die Zukunft nicht in derselben Weise wie über Vergangenes oder Gegenwärtiges lügen, weil die Zukunft keine Tatsache ist, sondern nur eine Möglichkeit.

Answer (score 3):

Keiner von beiden Ausdrücken passt in diesem Zusammenhang. Normalerweise drückt man es so aus:

> Aber da täuschen sie sich!

---

Lass mich den Unterschied zwischen *nur sich* und *sich nur* an einem anderen Beispiel verdeutlichen:

> Er hat **nur sich** entschuldigt. — nur sich, niemanden sonst
>
> Er hat sich **nur entschuldigt**. — nur entschuldigt, nichts sonst

Dieses Adverb *nur* qualifiziert immer das, was folgt. Genau wie zum Beispiel das Adverb *gern* oder das Adverb *nicht*. Nun ist es im Deutschen aber so, dass im Hauptsatz das konjugierte Verb vom Ende des Satzes an die zweite Position wandert. Das ist die sogenannte V2-Regel.

Im oberen Beispiel ist das konjugierte Verb *hat*. Lass es mich im Präsens formulieren:

> Er entschuldigt **nur sich.** — nur sich, niemanden sonst
>
> Er **entschuldigt** sich **nur.** — nur entschuldigt, nichts sonst

Dieses Verschieben des konjugierten Verbs ist die letzte Regel zur Reihenfolge der Satzglieder, die angewendet wird. Aus Sicht des *nur* steht da weiterhin:

> *Er (——) sich **nur entschuldigt.*** ← vor der Anwendung der V2-Regel!

Und genau dasselbe passiert auch in deinem Beispiel.